# How to get non-common value by comparing two values in SELECT query mysql?

Tags: mysql

For example I have a `SELECT` query that returning result of two columns called `ordered_zones` and `available_zone`. Both results zone name like below

[image: Original Result]

Expected result is result set to have one more column called `non_matching_zone`. This column value should come from `ordered_zones` by matching with `available_zone` that is non-common values like below

[image]

Can I achieve above result with query itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers. My problem gets solved with mysql `FIND_IN_SET` method by `IF(NOT FIND_IN_SET(ordered_zone, available_zones), ordered_zone, "") AS non_matching_zone`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `available_zone` always contain only one zone, you can replace `available_zone` value in `ordered_zones` with empty string

```
SELECT ordered_zones, available_zone, REPLACE(ordered_zones, available_zone, '') non_matching_zone
FROM table
```

Little work around is needed with commas, but that's the idea.